# Vagrant hangs after macOS upgrade

Tags: vagrant

After upgrading to macOS Mojave, my local vagrant stopped working with timeout error after `SSH auth method: private key as below:`

```
mch1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    mch1: SSH username: vagrant
    mch1: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

- Vagrant version : 2.2.2
- VirtualBoxVersion 5.2.22 r126460 (Qt5.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is an issue with the new security features on **Mojave**.

Please give the console app (from where you ran vagrant up, e.g. *iTerm2*) full write permissions on the disk

- System preferences
- Security & Privacy
- Privacy
- Full Disk Access

then restart console and try again.